# SSRS: Group by matching a pattern

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

How can I group by based on a pattern in column to calculate the total?
My table has the following columns: CustomerAccount (char30), AccountDesc varchar(200), AccountAmount1 (decimal), AccountAmount2,....., AccountAmount5.
The CustomerAccount is in this format: xxx.xxxx.xxxxx.
Some of the values are:

[image]

How do I group the data so any value like xxx.xxxx.31xxx, xxx.xxxx.32xxx, etc is grouped together so I can calculate the AccountAmount like the image below in SSRS report? The highlighted part ranges from 30 to 39:

[image]

I am not sure if it would be easier to do it in SQL query, but not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your account number is always a fixed length (or more precisely, if the numbers you want to group by are always in the same position) then you can create a row group with the group expression being something like

```
=MID(Fields!CustomerAccount.Value, 11,2)
```

If you wanted to group an everything up to that point you could do

```
=LEFT(Fields!CustomerAccount.Value, 13)
```

The numbers might be out by one as I can't remember if these are zero or 1 based functions but you'll soon notice that.

Comment: That works if the numbers are always in the same position, and the middle part of the number does not change. If we have xxxx.5050.30xxx, xxxx.5051.30xxx, how do we group by the middle part of the number first and then apply your logic to the last part? Thanks!

Comment: Just change the range of the MID function to cover the bit you want to sort by, so in the last comment you example was from position 6 and 7 characters long just change the 11,2 to 6,7. if this wont; work then you need to edit your question and supply a lot of examples of these account numbers so we can come up with a method that works for all.